# Loading Datagrip tables with descending order as default

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datagrip

I want load a table with thousands of row. Usually, I would alway view the last added record. When Jetbrains Datagrip first loads the table, they are in the ascending order - I see the first record added (with id = 1).

How do I make it load the table in descending order where I can see the last record added?

The purpose of this is to save time and not have to query the database like two time just to get it in descending order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it's impossible. We've created a ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-6704

Comment: Thanks for this. I expect this feature in another version

Answer (score 1):

For anyone arriving at this question now, you can go to this path and set a default order (ascending or descending) on your primary key when the tables are loaded:

`Settings -> Database -> Data Editor and Viewer -> Data Sorting -> Sort tables by numeric primary key : ASC/DESC`.

This is for DataGrip version `v2023.2.1`

Comment: Thank you so much! It also works in pycharm 2023.1.2

Comment: I applied ordering in desc order, but is still sorts it by the primary key in ascending order...